# C# DLL（クラスライブラリ）内のWindows Formを別プロセスで起動できますか？

Tags: c#, winforms

タイトルの件、exe形式のWindows Formであれば、Process.startで別プロセスで
起動できると思いますが、DLL内の特定Formクラスを別プロセスで起動する
方法はありますでしょうか？

ランチャ(exe)を別途用意して、Process.start(ランチャ.exe)を
実行し、ランチャ内でDLL内の特定のFormをリフレクションで作成して
起動する方法は、問題ないことを確認しておりますが、
ランチャを経由せずに起動する方法を探しております。

このあたり、ご存知の方がおりましたら
ご教示頂きたく、よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: ちなみにプロセスを分ける理由はなんでしょう？ 新しいウィンドウを開くだけではダメなのでしょうか？

Comment: プロセスを分ける理由は、起動元プロセスを落としても、起動した画面は生かしたままにするためとなります。

Comment: 画面を生かしたままにするためなら[以前のスレッドで紹介した方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/a/34847/4236)で済むのではと。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

そもそもプロセスの生成とは特定の実行可能ファイルを指定した引数や権限で開始することを指すわけですから、なんらかの実行可能ファイル＝「ランチャ」は必ず必要になります。

また実行ファイルのエントリポイント(`Program.Main`)は事前に定義する必要があり、プロセス外から変更することはできません。一般的には実行される側のプロセスがあらかじめコマンドライン引数などを参照しておき、他プロセスは引数を変えることで動作を変更する形になります。

ですので選択肢としては

1. 起動対象のフォームを含むソリューション側であらかじめ特殊な起動オプションを用意しておく

たとえば

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // 略
    Application.Run(new MainForm());
}
```

となっているところを

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    // 略
    if (args.Contains("/hoge"))
    {
        Application.Run(new HogeForm());
        return;
    }
    Application.Run(new MainForm());
}
```

のように起動処理を変えれば良いです。

2. 任意のフォーム型を引数に取りリフレクションで生成するアプリケーションを用意しておく
3. 動的コード生成を用いて要件にあったエントリポイントを含むアセンブリを実行時に出力する

ぐらいになるかと思います。

留意事項を挙げておくと.NETアプリケーションの構成はかなりの部分app.configに依存しています。ですので起動する実行可能ファイルを変えると参照アセンブリの解決などがうまく行かなくなる可能性も高いため、単純にリフレクションを使えばよいというものではありません。出来る限り呼び出される側で特殊な起動方法に対応する形にすべきだと思います。

Comment: ランチャは必ず必要とのこと理解いたしました。
起動するフォームは、固定化できないため（追加されていく仕様）のため
現状では、リフレクションでフォームを生成する予定です。

定義ファイルはできるだけ、個別のファイルにしてapp.configに
何か特別な定義は記載しない方針です。
参照アセンブリの解決がうまくいかなくなるとおっしゃっている
部分が気になりますが、何か問題になる例等を
簡単に示せましたら、ご教示頂きたいです。

Comment: 例えばNuGetでライブラリA, Bを参照しているとします。内部的にライブラリAはライブラリCのバージョン1.0.0を、ライブラリBは2.0.0を使用しているような場合、App.configにbindingRedirectという要素が書き込まれ、バージョン1.0.0への参照を2.0.0で代用する設定が追加されます。これがないとライブラリAはCを使用することが出来ず、実行時に落ちます。

Answer (score 1):

kunifさんも言及されていますが、ランチャー画面に表示を行わないFormにリンクを行うのは無駄ですのでお勧めできません。
とはいえ、質問に対してはお勧めのアプローチがあるので紹介します。

C#プロジェクトは次の３種類があります。

- Console Application
  コンソール（コマンドプロンプトの黒あれ）を表示する.EXE
- Windows Application
  コンソールを表示しない.EXE
- Class Library
  コンソールを表示しない.DLL

ネイティブの.EXE / .DLLと異なり.NETの.EXE / .DLLでは上記の差しかありません。つまり、.EXE形式であってもリンク（参照）することができます。（ネイティブではリンクを行うためには.DLLの必要があります。）

ですので、独立したプロセスとして起動したいFormはClass Library(.DLL)でなくWindows Application(.EXE)としてMainメソッドも用意しておき、ランチャープログラムからはこの.EXEを参照するとよいでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。exe形式で個々のアプリを作成して、ランチャにexeの内のフォームをリフレクションで生成して起動する方法がオススメと解釈致しました！